# Getting an object's list from inside another object

Tags: c#

This is the layout

```
     House -> HouseDef -> Room -> Door
                            L---> Windows
```

The problem is that any class may or may not have lists and nested classes like HouseDefinition does. The point is it should be flexible to handle any of these three cases for class variations: 
1. hasList, 
2. hasNestedObject with List inside that Nested Object
3. Has neither a List nor Nested class

Example of 1 being a Room class which contains a Window List
Example of 2 like House Class
Example of 3 like a Window Class

I have these two classes that I want to access generically from another class. I want to be able to get the Rooms List in House Definition by access of House class stored as an object in MyTreeNode. How can I do this not bound by types, or polymorphic to support a deeper hierarchy level in the future?

```
public class House
{
   string name;
   HouseDefinition definition;

   public string Name() { return name; }
   public HouseDefinition Definition {get {return definition;}}


   public House(string name,HouseDefinition definition)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.definition = definition;
   }
}

public class HouseDefinition
{
    private List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
    string type;

    public List<Room> Rooms { get { return rooms; } }
    public Room this[int i] { get { return rooms[i]; } }
    public HouseDefinition(string type)
    {
        DefaultLayout();
        this.type = type;
    }
}

    public class MyTreeNode : TreeNode
    {
        string label;
        IEnumerable items;
        bool hasList;
        object item;

        public string Label { get {return label; } }
        public IEnumerable Items { get { return items;} }
        public object Item { get { return item; } }

        public bool HasList { get { return hasList; } }

        public MyTreeNode(object item)
        {
            this.item = item;
            label = item.ToString();
            hasList = false;
        }
        public MyTreeNode(object item, IEnumerable Items)
        {
            this.item = item;
            label = item.ToString();
            hasList = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the intent of your question with a code example that you would like to achieve as a result?

Comment: not bound by type? What do you mean, can there be later different types in tree node and which one? Only House or HouseDefinition too? Also what do you mean by deeper hierarchy? Can it be Apartment->Houses->HouseDefinition or some other hierarchy? Can you share more concrete example

Comment: Try and think about it like this: *A manager (Employee) has a list of employees (List<Employee>) and down goes the hierarchy.* The important bit from this example is that `Employee` has a `List<Employee>` so try aiming for something similar for your case. That is a very high level suggestion I can give you based on the limited amount of information you have provided.

Comment: I have updated my description

Answer (score 0):

I think your classes look fine, but I would remove `HouseDefinition`, since those properties just seem like `House` to me. If you want to practice inheritance, you could create an `IBuilding` interface that forces `House`, `Mansion`, `Shack` to implement GetRooms() or something like that. A couple other things:

- Your `TreeNode` class should be using [generic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) like `public MyTreeNode(T item)`
- You should check out [autoimplemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#auto-implemented-properties) - the public fields automatically create private backing fields, so you don't need to create a private field and a getter like you did here: `public object Item { get { return item; } }`
- it's considered bad practice to use the "object" type, so you should convert those to the generic types mentioned above

Good luck, your code is looking good so far!

Comment: The HouseDefinition is needed specifically for house type like "Apartment" or "Mansion". House class is an instance that would contain a name like "My House". Having a composite class is part of the obstacle im trying to get through.

Comment: Hmm I think it could go either way. I would say an apartment isn't a "type" of "House" so maybe instead of "House," your class should be "Building"? These are just thoughts, take it or leave it!